# Load functions if there are not loaded yet in Databricks notebooks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I am coding Python in Databricks and I am using spark 2.4.5.

I have several notebooks for loading my dimention tables and my fact tables. I have two master notebooks for loading Dimensions and Facts.

I have developed some UDF for testing, auditing and loging. I need to add my UDF to each notebook. For now, I have below command on top of each notebook

```
%run ../Functions
```

But i am wondering if by doing that I am loading several times my UDFs when i am running all my notebooks!

I thought maybe I have to load juste one time my UDF in my Master Notebook but i don`t know what should i do in development time when i need to run my notebook seperatly.

Is it any way to verify on top of my notebooks if my UDFs are not loaded, run Functions notebook?

```
if (UDFs are not loaded) :
   %run ../Functions
```